# Can I access previous form values in submit handler in react hook form

Tags: react-hook-form

I have a react hook form where in the submit handler I want to work out the changed values to then send a patch request to the API. Can I access the default values in the submit handler..

```
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        reset,
      } = useForm<FormValues>({
        resolver: zodResolver(Schema),
        defaultValues: {
          field1: object.field1,
          field2: object.field2,
        },
      }); 

      const processForm: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = async (data) => {
        const changedValues = getChangedValues(data, defaultValues??);
        console.log('changedValues', changedValues)
      };
```

If I set the default values to a variable, after submit the variable would not get updated.